# Multiple VPC static default route & selection criteria

Tags: routes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vpc

I'm trying to deploy a routing design that allows for VPC traffic to egress through a 3rd party virtual firewall so I employ security inspection (IPS, ect).

I can easily set this up wit a single Firewall VM, adding a static default route pointing towards the Firewall VMs interface, and traffic flows through the VM as expected.

To survive a zonal failure, I'd like to add a second firewall and an accompanying second default route pointing towards it with a routing higher metric.

When I power down firewall VM #1, the GCP VPC Route UI indicates that the original route to VM#1 has issues (orange triangle) because the next-hop IP isn't available. But... the second default route (with a higher metric) doesn't replace the old route, so traffic won't forward to my second firewall VM.

Is there a way to have a route pulled when the route is no longer healthy, allowing higher priority routes to take effect?

Comment: not unless you setup some kind of monitoring and delete the route which you know is going to fail.

Answer (score 0):

As @doxthefox mentioned in his comment, you need to have some sort of monitoring set up in order to determine which route is being failed and then delete the route in order for the other one to take in effect.

Please keep in mind that if a next hop is not found for a particular route, the packet is dropped and the VPC network replies with an ICMP destination or network unreachable error.

I would suggested taking a look at this help center [article](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes#individualroutes) for more details about route selection on GCP.